# VSCodium crashes randomly on "escape" key in Mac OS Mojave. How can I find the issue?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, neovim

I'm using VSCodium on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.6. Specs of VSCodium:

```
Version: 1.45.1
Commit: 5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
Date: 2020-05-15T11:07:54.108Z (3 wks ago)
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0
```

I'm using the neovim plugin so I need the escape key quite a bit. Trouble is that this occasinally kills VS Code and gives me the following problem report:

```
Process:               Electron [29119]
Path:                  /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
Identifier:            com.visualstudio.code.oss
Version:               1.45.1 (1.45.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Electron [29119]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-06-08 13:52:23.661 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G5033)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        374121B4-C402-07B8-CC59-5BD03F617E73


Time Awake Since Boot: 250000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000069
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [29119]

VM Regions Near 0x69:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000106fd3000-0000000106ffc000 [  164K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron

Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108b635a5 0x10700b000 + 28673445
1   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010711d8fd 0x10700b000 + 1124605
2   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108b63569 0x10700b000 + 28673385
3   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010900e1a1 0x10700b000 + 33567137
4   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108eeb346 0x10700b000 + 32375622
5   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108e51691 0x10700b000 + 31745681
6   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108e77a87 0x10700b000 + 31902343
7   com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000107660dcf 0x10700b000 + 6643151
8   com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010968d717 0x10700b000 + 40380183
9   com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001096924ee 0x10700b000 + 40400110
10  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000109691d74 0x10700b000 + 40398196
11  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010968a753 0x10700b000 + 40367955
12  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010968afca 0x10700b000 + 40370122
13  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001096a139e 0x10700b000 + 40461214
14  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000109376342 0x10700b000 + 37139266
15  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001093862d4 0x10700b000 + 37204692
16  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001093867a7 0x10700b000 + 37205927
17  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001093e2de3 0x10700b000 + 37584355
18  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010931e98a 0x10700b000 + 36780426
19  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001093e274f 0x10700b000 + 37582671
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c88bd17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c88bcbd __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c86f67b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 195
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c86ec45 __CFRunLoopRun + 1189
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2c86e54e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 455
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2bacd1ab RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
26  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2baccee5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 603
27  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2baccc76 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff29e6477d _DPSNextEvent + 1135
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff29e6346b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff29e5d588 -[NSApplication run] + 699
31  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001093e35ec 0x10700b000 + 37586412
32  com.github.Electron.framework   0x00000001093e2118 0x10700b000 + 37581080
33  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000109386c88 0x10700b000 + 37207176
34  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010935ad07 0x10700b000 + 37027079
35  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108b61233 0x10700b000 + 28664371
36  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108b62792 0x10700b000 + 28669842
37  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108b5e4e6 0x10700b000 + 28652774
38  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108a1c9f2 0x10700b000 + 27335154
39  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000108a1c60e 0x10700b000 + 27334158
40  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010ab314d9 0x10700b000 + 62022873
41  com.github.Electron.framework   0x0000000107bc5a44 0x10700b000 + 12298820
42  com.github.Electron.framework   0x000000010700e154 AtomMain + 84
43  com.visualstudio.code.oss       0x0000000106fd39e0 0x106fd3000 + 2528
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff587fc3d5 start + 1
```

It doesn't happen all the time, and I don't know what the conditions are to reproduce it, so I'm hesitant to file a bug report. Also not sure whether it's VSCode or this VSCodium build. Turning off/removing the neovim plug-in does not fix the issue, the escape key (remapped to caps-lock) will still randomly crash the program.

Has anyone experienced something like this? How do I figure out what the issue is so I can solve it or file a proper bug report in the right place? Thanks.

Comment: A [bug report](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/358) has already been filed with VS Codium on March 13, so all you can really do is to wait for this to be fixed.

Comment: Super, thanks for the link!